# Graphics: How would you draw graphics on a second GUI that is opened by JButton?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, awt

Here is what I have. Please excuse my ignorance and lack of convention.
I am able to get a GUI open when clicking on the JButton; however, I cannot figure out — or find information — on how to draw graphics onto the GUI opened by the JButton.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Window extends JFrame {

    JFrame startGUI;
    JButton startButton;
    JPanel initialPanel;
    JLabel startButtonLabel;


    public Window() {

        startButton = new JButton();
        initialPanel = new JPanel();
        startButtonLabel = new JLabel("Start");

        startButton.addActionListener(new StartButtonListener());


        add(initialPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        initialPanel.add(startButton);
        startButton.add(startButtonLabel);




        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

    class StartButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            startButton.isSelected();

            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
            setVisible(false);
            frame2.setSize(800, 600);
            frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame2.setUndecorated(true);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }

        public void paint (Graphics g) {

            ImageIcon panel2 = new ImageIcon ("NOWNEW2.png");
            g.drawImage(panel2.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
            }
        }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {

        ImageIcon panel = new ImageIcon ("NOWNEW2.png");
        g.drawImage(panel.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

        try {

            File sound = new File("bensound-newdawn.wav");
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Please excuse my ignorance and lack of convention."* Please excuse my ignoring your question until you have implemented the (12) suggestions I put on your earlier question (moments ago). BTW - one I forgot to add. 13) `public class Window extends JFrame {` Window is a poor name for an extended `JFrame` because the AWT package also offers a `Window`. Call it something more specific like `GameWindow` or `GameMenuWindow`. 14) `public void paint (Graphics g) {` be sure to add `@override` notation to any changed method. I'm guessing that at least 1 of those method declarations will show an error.

Comment: Oh, and 15) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) (It's likely the 'menu' that launches the game should be either a `JDialog`/`JOptionPane` or an AWT based `SplashScreen`. 16) `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` should more likely be `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` and the user has no option to activate either when the window / frame is undecorated. 17) Choose tags carefully, as they will often determine who (and how many) get to see the question. I added the Swing tag on both, & java tag on this one!

Comment: Your help is much appreciated Andrew, thank you again! I will now continue to read what you provided to learn more.